# Redirection works BUT

Tags: .htaccess

I have set up a redirect from old domain to new domain and it works however there are links which is not redirecting properly....

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old.us$ [OR]
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.old.us$
     RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.new.com/$1 [R=301,L]
 </IfModule>
```

I am trying to redirect : `www.old.us/scripts/affiliate.pl?id=505` to `www.new.com`

but redirects like this : `www.new.com/scripts/affiliate.pl?id=505` results a **404** page.

Comment: Well, does `new.com` have that URL?

Comment: No, I wish to simply redirect that to the new.com homepage..

Comment: Ah. Then remove the `$1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old\.us$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.new.com/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Ah thanks guys.

Works now, however had to redirect www.new.com/scripts/affiliate.pl?id=505 on the new domain htaccess although now shows:

www.new.com?id=505....

Comment: Working perfectly now. Thank you Anubhava